# Is there a more dynamic way of adding listener to all components in parent?

Tags: java, swing, listener, user-input, jcomponent

Right now, I'm overriding `JFrame.addKeyListener(KeyListener)`, checking the components in it's content pane, then adding listeners to all those components (after using super to invoke the original method)

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
    public void addKeyListener(KeyListener l) {
        super.addKeyListener(l);
        for(Component c : getContentPane().getComponents()) {
            c.addKeyListener(l);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure if this is the normally practiced way of adding listeners to a hierarchy of components, but it's the only one I can think of. Is there something already built into the standard JDK that is meant for this?

Comment: The question is "why?" Through the use of Key Bindings, you can control the focus level that triggers a key event...

Comment: Emphasizing this once more: This sounds like you are looking for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: No need to ask why. Thanks for answering my question (showing me key bindings), but why else would I want to do it? I want KeyEvents to trigger no matter what has focus

Comment: Key bindings provide you with the ability to trigger key events (on certain key strokes).  They provide better focus control management, so your component doesn't have to have focus for the key event to be triggered. They are based on the `Action`s API which provides a self-contained and configurable object which can be applied to menus and buttons, reducing the need to replicate code or do awesome tumbling tricks with `ActionListener`s.  The "why?" is because, depending on what you are trying to do, Key Bindings might not be the best choice...

Comment: Thanks for all the info :) All I'm worried about is trigger key events no matter what is focused, as long as the app is open and in focused. I'll look into Key Binding, I've never heard of it before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> No need to ask why

Sure there is because anytime I see anybody using a KeyListener I know there is almost always a better way to solve the problem.

> I want KeyEvents to trigger no matter what has focus

Still not really very clear.

For example, people don't usually listen for KeyEvents on a JButton. An `ActionListener` is used to handle the keyboard press of a button. Or, a few people have already suggested `Key Bindings` which would probably be more appropriate.

Or maybe on text components you would use a `DocumentListener`.

Finally, if you really think you need to listen to all events then you can use an `AWTEventListener'. See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.

So yes, the why, is important.